# Meaning of ascii(my_field) & 8 <> 8 condition in SQL request

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hql

I'm working on a SQL script that contains this condition :

```
select *
from my_table
where ascii(my_field) & 8 <> 8;
```

What does it mean?

I would like to implement this request on a PySpark script but if I don't understand the meaning of this condition it will be hard to do it.

PS: the SQL script is a .hql

Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it mean where the ascii code of the value is not 8 (backspace)

<> is like x > y || x < y that equals to x!=y. (<> mean not equal of numbers)

& it is 'AND' operation on the bit of the value (8&8=8).

This sql is equal to:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table where my_field != ' '
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand now :)